# On Mac OSX Postgres is exiting from a "smart shutdown request" when started as a daemon but runs fine from command line

Tags: postgresql

When I start postgres on the command line using

```
sudo -u postgres /usr/local/postgresql/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/postgresql_data -l /tmp/pg_logfile start
```

it works just fine but if I create a launch daemon plist file and launch it in there like this (only the relevant section):

```
        <key>UserName</key>
        <string>postgres</string>
        <key>GroupName</key>
        <string>postgres</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
                <array>
                        <string>/usr/local/postgresql/bin/pg_ctl</string>
                        <string>start</string>
                        <string>-D/usr/local/postgresql_data</string>
                        <string>-l/tmp/pg_logfile</string>
                </array>
        <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
        <string>/usr/local/postgresql</string>
```

Then when I launch postgres using that launch daemon file, the pg_logfile shows me it starts up just fine but then gets a "smart shutdown request" and, about 100ms after starting up, it shuts down. Again, works just fine from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit up front that this took me way longer to figure out than it should have (I'm new to postgres). The key "duh" moment was realizing it was behaving just like a foreground process when you close a terminal window -- i.e., closing the window kills the foreground process. So then I realized when launchctl was done launching "pg_ctl" some process exited and pg_ctl was dying as a result.

Basically, "pg_ctl" is not a file you can run as a daemon, instead you should use the "postgres" command directly. Once I realized this and changed it in my launch daemon plist file, everything worked just fine.

Just took a lot longer for me to realize this than it should have. Corrected plist entry below:

```
        <key>UserName</key>
        <string>postgres</string>
        <key>GroupName</key>
        <string>postgres</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
                <array>
                        <string>/usr/local/postgresql/bin/postgres</string>
                        <string>-D/usr/local/postgresql_data</string>
                </array>
        <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
        <string>/usr/local/postgresql</string>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/var/log/postgres/postgresql.stdout</string>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/var/log/postgres/postgresql.stderr</string>
```